# extended floating action button for scrren swipe

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Hi I want to make an Extended floating action button when I swipe up my screen it will become shrink, and when I swipe down it will be extended. I tried a lot to search this answer but not found that's why I asked this question. thanks in advance

Comment: what does it mean shrink or extend  , do you want it visible and invisible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are making it visible or invisible using recyclerview scroll

then

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener( new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy < 0)
                floatingActionbutton.hide();
            else if (dy > 0)
                floatingActionbutton.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged( recyclerView, newState );
        }
    } );
```

Comment: I think I did it.I also want to increase my  reputation I don't know how to do it

Comment: suppose if I am not using recycler view and using scroll view then which method is used

Comment: increase reputatioin by giving right answer to others questioin and didnt try with scrollview may be just replace the object of recyclerview with scrollview try and find